# computing element-wise averages from matrices

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I've a set of matrices stored in text files. I would like to compute an output matrix resulting of the element-wise averages of the input matrices. An illustration is given below:

```
cat file1.txt
Item0 Item1
Item0 1.01456e+06 5
Item1 2 12.2


cat file2.txt
Item0 Item1
Item0 1.0274e+06 6
Item1 0 14.5


cat output.txt
Item0 Item1
Item0 1020980 5.5
Item1 1 13.35
```

Note that some of the values in the input matrices are in `engineering notation`.
All suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v row=2:3 -v col=2:3 -v num=2 '

BEGIN {
    split(row, r, ":")
    split(col, c, ":")
    n = num
}

r[1]<=FNR && FNR<=r[2] {
    for(i=c[1];i<=c[2];i++)
    {
        m[FNR,i]+=$i
    }
}

END {
    for(i=r[1];i<=r[2];i++)
    {
        for(j=c[1];j<=c[2];j++)
        {
            printf("%f\t", m[i,j]/n)
        }
        print ""
    }
}' file{1,2}.txt
```

---

```
1020980.000000  5.500000
1.000000        13.350000
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest doing this in two stages. First, convert the matrices to lines of (row number, column number, value) triples. I'll assume matrices without the row and column labels, for simplicity.

```
for f in file*.txt
do
  awk '{ for (n=1; n<=NF; n++) { print NR, n, $n } }' $f
done
```

This first step throws all the matrices together in a way that is more easily handled.

Next, calculate the averages by piping the triples into awk:

```
awk -v Rows=2 -v Cols=2 Mats=2 '
{
  sum[$1, $2] += $3
}

END {
  for (m=1; m<=Rows; m++) {
    for (n=1; n<=Cols; n++) {
      printf("%s ", sum[m, n])
    }
    printf("\n")
  }
}'
```

For simplicity, I've just passed in the numbers of rows, columns, and matrices as awk variables. You could instead determine those from the triples.