# how to add each element of a row from two files in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to write shell script which function as below description

1. Cat file1 and file2 which have x number of rows and column(Equal number of rows and column). Both files where created already.
2. Script should add(sum value of each element) each row's column element from file1 and file2 and generate output as file3. 
   file1-:
   10,10,10,10
   11,11,11,11
   file2-:
   5,5,5,5
   11,11,11
   file3 would have output-:
   15,15,15,15
   22,22,22,22

Comment: Not getting? like this `cat file file2 > file3`.? or `paste file1 file2 > file3`?

Comment: I want get sum of each element of a matrix from file1 and file2 in file3

Comment: What are sample input and output files?

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786210/computing-element-wise-averages-from-matrices

Comment: file1-:
10,10,10,10
11,11,11,11
file2-:
5,5,5,5
11,11,11
file3 would have output-:
15,15,15,15
22,22,22,22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to know `x`, the number of columns, you can simply sum up explicitly. For example, with `x=4`:

```
--- script.sh ---
#!/bin/bash    
while true; do
  read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 <&3
  read -r d1 d2 d3 d4 <&4
  if [ -z "$c1" -o -z "$d1" ]; then
    break
  fi
  echo "$(($c1 + $d1)) $(($c2 + $d2)) $(($c3 + $d3)) $(($c4 + $d4))" >>3.txt
done 3<1.txt 4<2.txt
```

Here's a sample run:

```
$ ./script.sh && cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 9 9 9

1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1

2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9
10 10 10 10
```

Comment: if each element of matrix is separated by comma, then output shown is not comming

Comment: @Deepak set the `IFS` to determine the separator, for example: `IFS=',' read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 <&3`

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a shell script, but I find this kind of task very easy to achieve using python.

So in case it helps anyone, here's a quick python script.  This script supports an arbitrary number of input files (one or more):

```
#! python
import sys
if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    raise RuntimeError('usage: %s file1 file2' % sys.argv[0])
for lines in zip(sys.args[1:]):
   print sum( float(line.strip()) for line in lines )
```

Comment: The virtues of python are many, but the OP mentioned they want a shell script ...

Comment: @mockinterface yes I agree. I think this answer is still worth posting, since it might be useful to someone (I find it exremely simple and readable), even if it's not a direct answer to the question.